# If there is a wall in the target node of PedGoTo, an error occurs. What should I do to move to the non-wall

Tags: anylogic

[image]

The process of moving people to nodes sometimes leads to errors that prevent them from moving to the walls.

How can I move a person inside a node, not a wall

I tried to solve the problem through the context function, but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

The `PedGoTo` block lets you specify explicit X-Y coordinates:
[image]

Just specify coordinates within your node and off you go :)

Answer (score 0):

this is un unfortunate issue in Anylogic... what you have to do is to change your rectangular nodes to polygonal nodes and draw them carefully like this:

[image]